# NoSQL Database - Saving JSON Files on Local Server instead of a Database Server

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

What are the disadvantages of saving json files on the virtual machine you paid for instead of saving it in a database like MongoDB (security concerns, efficiency,...)?

I have tried using both ways of storing data but still couldn't find any difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably faster to store the JSON files simply as files in your filesystem of the virtual machine.

Unless you need to do one or more of the following:

- Use a query language to extract parts of the JSON files.
- Search the JSON files efficiently.
- Allow clients on multiple virtual machines to access the same JSON data via an API.
- Enforce access controls, so some clients can access some JSON data.
- Make a consistent backup copy of the data.
- Store more JSON data than can fit on a single virtual machine.
- Enforce a schema so the JSON files are assured to have consistent structure.
- Update JSON data in a way that is assured to succeed completely, or else make no change.
- Run aggregate queries like COUNT(), MAX(), SUM() over a collection of JSON files.

You could do all these things by writing more code. It will take you years to develop that code to be bug-free and well-optimized.

By the end, what would you have developed?

You'd have developed a database management system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for small data you won't probably find the difference. Rather you may find that the data from you VM takes less time to return because you're not sending request to another remote server.

But when your data grows it will be hard to maintain. That's why we use a database management system to manage and process our data efficiently.

So, if you are storing small configuration file then you can use your filesystem for that otherwise I definitely recommend using a DBMS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you think of using folders to structure the JSON files properly? Example: Dividing a customers database alphabetically into 1 file (a, b, c, d,...). We can divide even divide it further (aa, ab, ac, ad, ae,...). For processing data, it is also possible to process it using the concept above.

Comment: Again, I don't recommend that because it won't scale very well and this is not how it's done in professional projects. But if it is small application and you're just practicing then go ahead.